# Pipes between child processes blank line issue

Tags: pipe

I have the following code. It's supposed to loop and create pipes depending on amount of commands. But since I have trouble making it work properly, I'm currently only testing with piping 2 commands which each are run in seperate processes. The issue is that a blank link is left at the bottom. I've read that you have to close the parent's pipes, but I can't make it work.

```
int pipeCount = commands- 1;
int fd[pipeCount][2];
createPipes(pipeCount, fd);

for (int i = 0; i < commands; i++) {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        dupPipes //This function duplicates the pipes to STDIN and STDOUT & closes the pipes correctly
        execCommand //Executes the commands properly
    } else {
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    }
}
```

This code is working fine, the issue is that a blank line is at the bottom and wherever I try to close the parent's pipes. Then the program stops functioning and it cannot duplicate the pipes in the child processes.

INPUT:

> myShell$ ls | tr a-z A-Z

OUTPUT:

```
stuff
stuff2
<BLANK LINE>
```